# How to debug a parsererror in solidity

Tags: deployment, solidity

I need assistance here. I don't know why I keep having this error. I have added the ";" but I keep seeing the **parser error** message. I am supposed to compile and deploy the contract.

```
pragma solidity  ^0.5.7;

contract Coin {
    address public minter;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    event sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    constructor() {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }

    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == minter);
        balances[require] += amount;
    }

    error InsufficientBalance(uint requested, uint available);

    function send(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        if(amount > balances[msg.sender])
           revert InsufficientBalance({
                requested: amount,
                available: balances[msg.sender]
            });    
        
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: [tag:parser] says "Don't use this tag for questions about…parse errors in a particular programming language (use the appropriate language tag instead)."

Comment: Also, when you ask about an error message, please paste the complete message, and indicate which line (and column if the information is available.) Finally, life is to short to scroll. Please simplify the lives of the people who are willing to help you by formatting it correctly, without excessive vertical whitespace.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or actual question you're asking. *this issue* has absolutely no meaning. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future user of the site who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem, and your current title is absolutely useless in that regard. Providing a proper title will help get your question in front of people who can answer it more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Change your compiler version in your smart contract from:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;
```

to

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
```

Another problem that I identified is the struct in this instruction:

```
balances[require] += amount;
```

you must to change the key value of `balances` mapping with the address parameter passed it into the `mint()` function, in this way:

```
balances[receiver] += amount;
```

Comment: I have changed the compiler version and its still not working.